# Gradle building error in android Studio when adding Room Library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I am getting an error in my `build.gradle` file when I am adding the Room library in my project

Here is my `build.gradle`

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mvp_sample_todolist"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary(true)

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"


}
```

Following is the error I am getting

```html
Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.
   > Could not find annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.1.0/annotation-1.1.0.jar
```

I even tried to delete the project's gradle file but still, it didn't work.
If anyone knows how to resolve this error please help.

Comment: You are missing 'kapt' https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#kts

Comment: I am using Java so I cant set 'kapt'

Comment: As I see, you're an Iranian, it might be due to the sanctions, use a good vpn like ProtonVPN or a proxy like [Freedom of Devs](http://fodev.org)

Comment: I set the proxy but it doesn't make different  @Amin